# Is there a way in linq wherin i can insert a row(from dictionary) in datatable using the list of column names c#?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core

I have a `List<Dictionary<string,string>>` something like this: 
[0] key1 val,key2 val,key3 val 
[1] key1 val,key2 val,key3 val 
[2] key1 val,key2 val,key3 val

And i have a list of column names in the same order as columns in the datatable.
I want to filter only those keys which are there inside the list from the dictionary and also insert it in the proper order.

I'm able to filter the required keys to be inserted but then how do i insert it in the proper order in linq.

```
var colList = new List<string>() { "key3", "key1"};
dict.ForEach(p => jsonDataTable.Rows.Add(p.Where(q=>colList.Contains(q.key)).Select(r => r.Value).ToArray()));
```

I cannot do like this because number of columns will vary and also the method must work when we pass any list of column names:

```
foreach(var item in dict)
 jsonDatatable.Rows.Add(item[colList[0]], item[colList[1]]);
```

Please suggest some ways.

Comment: can you please post the sample output that you need

Answer (score 1):

> LINQ will never ever change the input sources. You can only extract data from it.

### Divide problems in subproblems

The only way to change the input sources is by using the extracted data to update your sources. Make sure that before you update the source you have materialized your query (= ToList() etc)

You can divide your problem into subproblems:

- Convert the table into a sequence of columns in the correct order
- convert the sequence of columns into a sequence of column names (still  in the correct order)
- use the column names and the dictionary to fetch the requested data.

By separating your problem into these steps, you prepare your solution for reusability. If in future you change your table to a DataGridView, or a table in an entity framework database, or a CSV file, or maybe even JSON, you can reuse the latter steps. If in future you need to use the column names for something else, you can still use the earlier steps.

To be able to use the code in a LINQ-like way, my advice would be to create extension method. If you are unfamiliar with extension methods, read [Extension Methods Demystified](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx)

You will be more familiar with the layout of your table (System.Data.DataTable? Windows.Forms.DataGridView? DataGrid in Windows.Controls?) and your columns, so you'll have to create the first ones yourself. In the example I use MyTable and MyColumn; replace them with your own Table and Column classes.

```
public static IEnumerable<MyColumn> ToColumns(this MyTable)
{
     // TODO: return the columns of the table
}

public static IEnumerable<string> ToColumnNames(this IEnumerable<MyColumn> columns)
{
    return columns.Select(column => ...);
}
```

If the column name is just a property of the column, I wouldn't bother creating the second procedure. However, the nice thing is that it hides where you get the name from. So to be future-changes-proof, maybe create the method anyway.

You said these columns were sorted. If you want to be able to use `ThenBy(...)` consider returning an `IOrderedEnumerable<MyColumn>`. If you won't sort the sorted result, I wouldn't bother.

Usage:

```
MyTable table = ...
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = table.ToColumns().ToColumnNames();
```

or:

```
IEnumerable<string> columnNames = table.ToColumns()
    .Select(column => column.Name);
```

The third subproblem is the interesting one.

### Join and GroupJoin

> In LINQ whenever you have two tables and you want to use a property of the elements in one table to match them with the properties of another table, consider to use (Group-)Join.

If you only want items of the first table that match exactly one item of the other table, use `Join`: "Get Customer with his Address", "Get Product with its Supplier". "Book with its Author"

On the other hand, if you expect that one item of the first table matches zero or more items from the other table, use `GroupJoin`: "Schools, each with their Students", "Customers, each with their Orders", "Authors, each with their Books"

Some people still think in database terms. They tend to use some kind of `Left Outer Join` to fetch "Schools with their Students". The disadvantage of this is that if a School has 2000 Students, then the same data of the School is transferred 2000 times, once for every Student. `GroupJoin` will transfer the data of the School only once, and the data of every Student only once.

### Back to your question

In your problem: every column name is the key of exactly one item in the Dictionary.

What do you want to do with column names without keys? If you want to discard them, use `Join`. If you still want to use the column names that have nothing in the Dictionary, use `GroupJoin`.

```
IEnumerable<string> columNames = ...
var result = columnNames.Join(myDictionary,

    columName => columName,                // from every columName take the columnName,
    dictionaryItem => dictionaryItem.Key,  // from every dictionary keyValuePair take the key

    // parameter resultSelector: from every columnName and its matching dictionary keyValuePair
    // make one new object:
    (columnName, keyValuePair) => new
    {
        // Select the properties that you want:
        Name = columnName,

        // take the whole dictionary value:
        Value =  keyValuePair.Value,

        // or select only the properties that you plan to use:
        Address = new
        {
            Street = keyValuePair.Street,
            City = keyValuePair.City,
            PostCode = keyValuePair.Value.PostCode
            ...
        },
    });
```

If you use this more often: consider to create an extension method for this.

> Note: the order of the result of a Join is not specified, so you'll have to Sort after the Order

Usage:

```
Table myTable = ...
var result = myTable.ToColumns()
                    .Select(column => column.Name)
                    .Join(...)
                    .Sort(joinResult => joinResult.Name)
                    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering on the List<Dictionary<string, string>>, filter on the `colList` so that you will get in the same order and only if the colList is available in the `List<Dictionary<string, string>>`

This is as per my understanding, please comment if you need the result in any other way.

```
var dictAllValues = dict.SelectMany(x => x.Select(y => y.Value)).ToList();
// Now you can filter the colList using the above values
var filteredList = colList.Where(x => dictAllValues.Contains(x));

// or you can directly add to final list as below
jsonDataTable.Rows.AddRange(colList.Where(x => dictAllValues.Contains(x)).ToList());
```